# Share histogram bins across columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to create a series of histograms (from a `pd.DataFrame`). I would like different quantities (`fare` in the example below) in different rows and different classes (`class` in the example below) in different columns, as follows:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
df = pd.melt(titanic, id_vars=["sex", "class"], value_vars=["fare", "age"])
sns.displot(
    data=df,
    x="value",
    row="variable",
    col="class",
    hue="sex",
    facet_kws={"sharex": "row", "sharey": "row"},
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Unfortunately, because of the `common_bins=True` parameter it seems that the axis are shared both across the rows and across the columns, which I don't want because different rows have different quantities that can be in very different ranges. Using `common_bins=False` I get the following:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
df = pd.melt(titanic, id_vars=["sex", "class"], value_vars=["fare", "age"])
sns.displot(
    data=df,
    x="value",
    row="variable",
    col="class",
    hue="sex",
    facet_kws={"sharex": "row", "sharey": "row"},
    common_bins=False,
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In this case the axis are shared only across the same row as I want (which is better suited to represent quantities with different ranges), but the bins are not shared anymore. I'd like the bins to be shared across columns, or at least in the same histogram (but much preferably across columns).

I also tried to use `sns.FacetGrid` directly, but in such case it does not seem possible to get a legend [as discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2472#issuecomment-774494231). The following shares the axis on the same row and has shared bins within the same histogram, but does not produce a legend based on `hue`:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="class", row="variable", sharex="row", sharey="row")
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x="value",  hue="sex").add_legend()
```

[image]

**Is there a simple way to share bins and axis on the same row and get a legend based on `hue`?** Essentially the last figure but with the legend of the first two figures (and possibly bins shared across the same row).

Comment: Is the third plot what you want aside from the absence of the legend? It doesn't look like the bins are shared across the columns there? My advice had been to manually loop over the FacetGrid axes, not to try and go through `.map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FacetGrid` is designed to show the same x/y relationship in every facet. If that's not what you're trying to do, you may have more success using a more procedural approach. Here's one idea where we use `FacetGrid` to set up the figure but loop over the axes individually.

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
df = pd.melt(titanic, id_vars=["sex", "class"], value_vars=["fare", "age"])

binwidths = {"fare": 20, "age": 5}

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="class", row="variable", sharex="row", sharey="row", height=2.5)
for (var, cls), ax in g.axes_dict.items():
    sns.histplot(
        data=titanic[titanic["class"] == cls],
        x=var, hue="sex",
        binwidth=binwidths[var],
        ax=ax, legend=ax is g.axes.flat[-1])

g.set_titles(template="{col_name} {col_var}")
plt.setp(g.axes[1], title="")
sns.move_legend(ax, loc="lower left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: After updating to 0.11.2, this works like a charm. Thank you!